# Control Socket InputStream and OutputStream from Fragment (Android)

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-fragments

I have created a runnable class (Thread) witch connects to server, send and receives messages.

```
public class ConnectAndReceiveData implements Runnable{
    private BufferedReader inputBuffer;
    private String incomeText;
    private DataOutputStream outputStream;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            if(socket.isConnected()){
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes("Hello");
            }

            inputBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (inputBuffer.ready()) {
                    incomeText = inputBuffer.readLine();
                    System.out.println(incomeText);

                }
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But all the previous code is inside the main activity.

Is there any possibility to get the inputStream or the outputStream or the whole socket in a fragment??

I tried to add the socket inside a parcable object and then to pass it to the fragment but i was not successful.

I hope you can help me!!!

Comment: Get rid of the `ready()` test. It won't save you from blocking in `readLine()`, and in any case spin-looping is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a getSocket method in main activity

```
public void Socket getSocket(){
      return socket
}
```

To get the socket form fragment i just write the follow inside the onCreateView method

```
Socket socket = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSocket();
```